# Curry function in scala

Tags: scala

```
object answer {
    def product(f:Int=>Int)(a:Int,b:Int):Int =
        if (a>b) 1
        else f(a) * product(f)(a+1,b)   
    product(x=>x*x)(3,4)
    def fact(n:Int) = product(x=>x)(1,n)
}
```

I can answer the result of this execution it like this:

```
    // 3*3* product(f)(4,4)
    // 3*3 * (4*4) * product(f)(5,4)
    // 3*3 * 4*4 * 1
    // 3*3 * 4*4
    // 144
```

However I dont I understand this block of code 
`product(f)(a+1,b)`  anyone can explain me about that line?

Comment: What don't you understand? `product` is a recursive function

Comment: prouduct (f) this line?

Comment: Scala allows you to pass functions as arguments so `f` is defined as a function which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. You can see an example  implementation of that: `product(x=>x*x)(3,4)`. In this case, the function is simply multiplying the `Int` that was passed. Inside of product, the value of `a`(which was 3) is passed into the function in the `else` block `f(a)`

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block of code `product(f)(a+1,b)` is a call of method `product` with arguments: `f`, `a+1` and `b`.

More details:

`product` is a recursive higher-order function with multiple parameter lists.

- It is recursive since there is a call to itself in its body.
- It is higher-order since it takes a function as an argument (see [higher-order functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html)).
- It has two parameter lists (see [currying](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html)):

  - the first one consist of a single parameter: a function `f:Int=>Int`;
  - the second contains two parameters: `a: Int` and `b: Int`.

Comment: but f should has one Int parameter `f:Int=>Int` ,  right? and why product(f) no any parameter for f , could help to clarify . thanks

Comment: `f` is itself a parameter of type `Int=>Int` and it can be conveyed to other functions in the same way as any other. The first argument of function `product` shall be of type `Int=>Int` so `f` has appropriate type.

Comment: sorry , just not clear, and so f(a)  in this case `a` is parameter of `f` and `a` type`Int` , is possible to do like `product(f(a))(a+1,b)` ?

Comment: No, it won't compile since `f(other)` will have type `Int` (remember that `f` is a function from `Int` to `Int`) but `product` requires an argument of type `Int => Int`.

Answer (score 2):

`product` is a recursive function. Let's dissect it a bit.

```
def product(f:Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int
```

`product` takes in `f` which in this case is a function from `Int` to `Int`. Also, it takes in `a` and `b` which are both ints. In the case of this function, `a` and `b` would be the interval on which the `product`  function will be applied to.

Now, the part where you don't understand is this: `product(f)(a + 1, b)` right. Basically, what it does is after you have applied `f` to `a`, you need to apply `f` to the rest of the values in your interval. That is, since `a` is done, you need to compute starting on the next integer value which is `a + 1`.

Comment: and what (f) mean? and the (a + 1, a) is the parameter of f or parameter of product?

Comment: (a + 1, b) is the parameter of product in which `(f)` can use.  `f` there is a function that is taken in as a parameter of `product`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's figure out what is curry function. In general, curry function has two function parameters in two brackets. When we specify a parameter, the function will return another function with only one parameter. for example:

```
def sumInt1(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = {a + b}
def sumInt2(c: Int): Int = sumInt1(3)(c)
val test = sumInt2(5)  // test: 8
```

And, in `product(f)(a+1,b)`, only differ from the above example is that `f` is a function, and the function can also be viewed as a parameter in scala.